# Check title Attribute with multiple values in Jquery

Tags: jquery, title, html

I need to check `title` attribute of a control with multiple values. Means `title` of control may be any of some 3 values.

For example :

```
alert($("table span[title='Excel']").text());
```

here `title` could be `PDF` or  `CSV` too.

So how could we check `title` of `span` with multiple values using one selector.

for example:

```
$("table span[title='Excel'] || [title='2ndValue'] || [title='3rdValue']")
```

Comment: Why do you want only one selector...

Comment: I could check it using if statements too. But i need one only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `,` to separate your selector:

```
$("table span[title='Excel'], table span[title='2ndValue'], table span[title='3rdValue']");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M8zn8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.filter()` in your context,

```
var title == "";

$("table span[title]").filter(function(){
 title = $(this).attr('title');
 return title === "title1" || title === "title2" || title === "title3";
});
```